# Problem with Minecraft map starting to be drawn from the very top

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I crafted a map, used it, then enlarged it by crafting more paper onto it.

However, the point from which I did this is right at the very top of the map, so it doesn't help me map anything much north of that point. Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 7):

The Minecraft Wiki [has this one covered](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map#Zoom_out):

> Maps after 1.8 are always aligned to a grid at all zoom levels. That means zooming out any map in a specific area covered by that map will always have the same center, regardless of where the map was originally centered. As such maps will be aligned by map width (1024 blocks for a level 3 maps) minus 64. As such a level 3 map generated at spawn will cover X and Z coordinates from -64 to 960. All maps generated in this area will zoom out to the same coordinates, guaranteeing that they are always 'aligned' on a map wall.
>
> Map players dislike this change as it means their base will not be 'near center' in a zoomed out map. However when exploring the world while mapping it, you can create the next map immediately on entering that new maps area. Previous to 1.8, you would need to make your way 'without a map' to the center point before you can create and zoom out the map, and then have to backtrack to fill in the area you just covered.

Comment: Basically, The reason the map started at the top was because you were at the edge of the grid that your map was centred on.

Comment: This still makes no sense why they thought this was better than just centering maps so we can actually use them because currently all the zoom levels are either too zoomed in or too zoomed out and the blocks for each pixel of the map are too big so you're looking at an extremely low res map even at the max zoom out level. Basically, maps are useless. And the cartography table is pointless they could have just added the map recipes to the crafting table instead